# Python get list of list values in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

If I have the following dictionary...

```
location_ids: = 
{
'2c50b449-416e-456a-bde6-c469698c5f7': ['422fe2d0-b10f-446d-ac3c-f75e5a3ff138'], 
'61df50b6-3b50-4f22-a175-404089b2ec4f': ['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f']
}
```

... and what I want to do is get a list of the values from the lists in one list.

At the mo, I can do something like:

```
locations = [location_ids[i] for i in location_ids]
```

which returns a list of lists:

```
[
   ['422fe2d0-b10f-446d-ac3c-f75e5a3ff138'], 
   ['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f']
]
```

But, how can I change my code to just give me a list of the values like this:

```
['422fe2d0-b10f-446d-ac3c-f75e5a3ff138', '7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f']
```

I'm hoping as well, if I have more than one id in a values list, like this:

```
locations_id = {
'2c50b449-416e-456a-bde6-c469698c5f7': ['422fe2d0-b10f-446d-ac3c-f75e5a3ff138','d45ec64a-b41a-41d5-bd47-eed27c6dfd82'], 
'61df50b6-3b50-4f22-a175-404089b2ec4f': ['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f']
}
```

how can I expand my code to give me:

```
[
'422fe2d0-b10f-446d-ac3c-f75e5a3ff138',
'd45ec64a-b41a-41d5-bd47-eed27c6dfd82', 
'7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f'
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. This does help. It seems one way is to get my list of list values as suggested with locations = [location_ids[i][0:] for i in location_ids] and then do a second step with locations_flat = [item for sublist in locations for item in sublist].  Just wondering if there a way to do this in one elegant line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
locations = [location_ids[i][0] for i in location_ids]
```

You can select the first element of each lists :)

Comment: Thanks. This works nicely. What if I have more than one id in my values list? so locations_id = {'2c50b449-416e-456a-bde6-c469698c5f7': ['422fe2d0-b10f-446d-ac3c-f75e5a3ff138','d45ec64a-b41a-41d5-bd47-eed27c6dfd82'], '61df50b6-3b50-4f22-a175-404089b2ec4f': ['7112fa59-63b1-4057-8822-fe11168c328f']}

Comment: You can write : locations = sum(list(locations_id.values()), [])

Comment: @0xDEADBEEF summing over lists is quite inefficient, as it creates multiple new lists in the process (this is noted in the top answer on the proposed duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/3001761).

Comment: oh, i didn't know that, thanks @jonrsharpe